# Tkinter Widget won't disappear even if I use destroy/pack_forget

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I'm learning GUI, and as a test I'm trying to develop a frame with two radio buttons, one for random simulation and one for file input simulation. When I want a file input simulation the file name is needed, so I meant my second radio button to pack new Label/Entry throught the switch_entry command. The method called also should delete the Label and the entry if the first radio button is selected.

I tried pack_forget and destroy, but the result is I achieve to create de Label/Entry by selecting the second radio button, but can't destroy them by selecting the first. As I select first and second radio buttons alternatively, the GUI keeps adding label/entry sets. Code and image follow:

```
import tkinter as tk


class InterRiver(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        self.mode = tk.StringVar(value="Random")
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.lblChooseMode = tk.Label(self, text="Opções do Simulador").pack(side="top")
        self.rdModeRndm = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Rio Aleatório", value = "Random", variable = self.mode,
                                         command = self.switch_entry).pack(anchor="w", side="top")
        self.rdModeFile = tk.Radiobutton(self, text = "Rio a partir de arquivo", value= "File", variable = self.mode,
                                         command = self.switch_entry).pack(anchor ="w", side="top")
        self.btnStart= tk.Button(self, text = "Simular", command = simular).pack(side = "bottom")
        self.lblCycles = tk.Label(self, text = "Número de Ciclos").pack(side="top")
        self.ntyCycles = tk.Entry(self).pack(side="top")
    def switch_entry(self):
        lblFile = tk.Label(self, text="Insira o nome do arquivo")
        ntyFile = tk.Entry(self)
        if self.mode.get() == "File":
           lblFile.pack(side="top")
           ntyFile.pack(side="top")
        else:
           lblFile.destroy()
           ntyFile.destroy()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = tk.Tk()
    InterRiver(w).pack()
    w.title("Bears and Fishes")
    w.mainloop()
```

[image: Repeated Label/Entries]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ate trying to destroy something you haven't packed when you do destroy, since you create it at the beginning of `switch_entry`, and then either pack it or destroy it. Your `switch_entry` function should be:

```
    if self.mode.get() == "File":
       self.lblFile = tk.Label(self, text="Insira o nome do arquivo")
       self.ntyFile = tk.Entry(self)
       self.lblFile.pack(side="top")
       self.ntyFile.pack(side="top")
    else:
       self.lblFile.destroy()
       self.ntyFile.destroy()
```

Actually, a quicker way of doing it would be to put these lines in `__init__`:

```
       self.lblFile = tk.Label(self, text="Insira o nome do arquivo")
       self.ntyFile = tk.Entry(self)
```

And then in `switch_entry`:

```
    if self.mode.get() == "File":
       self.lblFile.pack(side="top")
       self.ntyFile.pack(side="top")
    else:
       self.lblFile.pack_forget()
       self.ntyFile.pack_forget()
```

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure instead of just deleting and repacking widgets, I think you can just pack different objects of different frames and use `lift()`

Comment: I had tried that, but when I selected the 1st radio button, triggering switch_entry, I got this error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):(...)
 line 25, in switch_entry
    lblFile.destroy()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'lblFile' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Suri Tried Pygasm's suggestion or my answer?

Comment: Creating the widgets  in __init__ did work! Thanks for the answers, @Artemis Fowl, and Pygasm. I'll study the usage of lift() as soon as I have time, since I'm in a hurry to finish the project. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yet, I don't really understand why It would work in ____init____, but not in a method. Maybe with time I'll do...